# Android: how to wait until LocationService sets GlobalVars before getting location

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

i have a `LocationService` class (extends `Service` implements `LocationListener`) that works constantly updates a global variable whenever a new location is obtained via the `onLocationChanged` method.

in the `onCreate` method of my launcher activity, i start this service. the next thing i do is to call a web service that takes in the latitude and longitude from the global variable.

this gives me a `NullPointerException` on the location global variable and i am assuming its because the service is running on a separate thread and have not obtained a location yet.

Question: how do i make it such that i will only call the web service only when a location has been obtained from the service class?

thanks so much. :)

Comment: Why don't you call your web service operation within `onLocationChanged` method of your `LocationService`? If it is a lengthy operation, you can always wrap it in `AsyncTask`.

Comment: hmmm because LocationService is only used to keep track of the user's current location via GlobalVars. i will then call different web services depending on which screen the user is on and send in the latest location from GlobalVars

Comment: So, how about registering a listener, that handles web service operations, to `LocationService`, at the beginning of each activity.

Comment: this sounds like a plan to me. do you mind elaborating a little further? i am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`YourService` informs every registered `LocationOperator` when location is changed. `LocationOperator` is a simple interface, declares `operate(Location)` method.

```
class YourService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private List<LocationOperator> listeners = new ArrayList<LocationOperator>();

    public List<LocationOperator> getListeners() {
            return listeners;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            for (LocationOperator listener : listeners) {
                    listener.operate(location);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // request location updates from `LOCATION_SERVICE`
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    //...
}
```

Start and connect to this service from your main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static YourService yourService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        Intent service = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
        startService(service);
        bindService();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can reach this service over `MainActivity` and register for `Location`

```
public class OperatorActivity extends Activity implements LocationOperator {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        // ...
        MainActivity.yourService.getListeners().add(this);
        // ...
    }

    public void operate(Location location) {
        // use location
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks for the code! i really learnt something from this. i had imagine i should remove the listener from the arraylist when the activity is destroyed? on a sidenote though, this will not work if i dont want to call my web service every time i change my location right. i was more hoping to refresh my data subsequently only when the user taps on refresh. which is why i was planning to use the LocationService to change the GlobalVars such that it will contain the latest location information whenever i refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not good wait for it (depends of the time wasted) because the activity can never start but you can try with this simple code:

```
While(latitude == null);
use latitude and longitude
continue with oncreate...
```

But my advice is that try to check it with other AsyncTask for dont do an active waiting. Hope it helps you.

Comment: `While(latitude == null);` keeps spinning like crazy and is not a good idea

Comment: Yes I said that is an active waiting and only should use in case that you get the information fast.

Comment: yeah i tried running a while loop to wait but it was like processing for a long time and nothing happened. perhaps in the while loop the LocationService thread to update location never got to run?

Comment: You should start the LoactionService before the while. If nothing happens, check if the service is changing the variable.